# Why isn't my Pappus chain lining up?

Tags: geometry

**TL;DR** Why isn't my Pappus chain lining up?

- **Visualisation:** http://jan.jarfalk.se/pappus-chain/
- **Proof:** http://jan.jarfalk.se/pappus-chain/debug.html
- **Code:** https://github.com/janjarfalk/pappus-chain

[image: My Pappus chain visualisation]

I saw a [Youtube clip on the Pappus chain on Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG_6nlMZ8f4&list=UUoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A) and I decided to create an animated visualisation of it. It looks [nice and pretty](http://jan.jarfalk.se/pappus-chain/) until you [study it](http://jan.jarfalk.se/pappus-chain/debug.html).

Shouldn't the midpoint of the circles creating the chain line up? I'm not sure if I have a programming problem or a maths problem, but since I'm a far better programmer than I'm a mathematician I'm guessing I'm having a maths problem. To be honest, I'm no mathematician at all. I didn't know what a Pappus chain was three days ago.

If there's an error with my calculations they are probably [here](https://github.com/janjarfalk/pappus-chain/blob/gh-pages/app/index.js):

```
60:    var val = (i * i * s * s + pulse) / 2;
61:    var x = i * pulse * s / val;
62:    var y = (pulse * (1 + pulse) / (2 * val)) - 1;
63:    var r = pulse * s / (2 * val);
```

Me not getting the Pappus chain at all is another possible explanation. :)

Thanks in advance for any idea, help or speculation that could help me figure this out.

Comment: The centers should lie on an ellipse, right?

Comment: @Alan Ah, as in not necessarily a circle?

Comment: Yup, looks very nice though.